# Dynamic shape graphic c#

Tags: c#, graphics, windows-forms-designer

I want to draw graphics (shapes) onto the panel to the top left. The shape will be drawn depending on the shape chosen and the value given by the track bar. The track bar values aren't specific i.e aren't pixels or millimeters, so basically when the track bar increases in number the shape should get larger.
[image]

This is the my main code. Other classes such as Circle, Square and Triangle also exist.

```
public partial class drawShape : Form
{

    Graphics drawArea;
    public decimal area;
    double myBoundary = 0;
    double myArea = 0;
    public double length = 100;

    public drawShape()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        drawArea = pnlDrawArea.CreateGraphics();
    }

    public void updateShape()
    {
        if(rbCircle.Checked)
        {
            drawCircle();
        }

        if(rbSquare.Checked)
        {
            drawSquare();
        }

        if(rbTriangle.Checked)
        {
            drawTriangle();
        }

        if(rb2DecimalPlaces.Checked)
        {
            lblBoundaryLength.Text = myBoundary.ToString("#,0.00");
            lblAreaResult.Text = myArea.ToString("#,0.00");
        }

        if(rb3DecimalPlaces.Checked)
        {
            lblBoundaryLength.Text = myBoundary.ToString("#,0.000");
            lblAreaResult.Text = myArea.ToString("#,0.000");
        }

        if(rb4DecimalPlaces.Checked)
        {
            lblBoundaryLength.Text = myBoundary.ToString("#,0.0000");
            lblAreaResult.Text = myArea.ToString("#,0.0000");
        }
    }

    public void drawCircle()
    {
        Circle myCircle = new Circle(length);
        myArea = myCircle.GetArea(length);
        myBoundary = myCircle.GetCircumference();
        lblAreaResult.Text = myArea.ToString();
        lblBoundaryLength.Text = myBoundary.ToString();
    }

    public void drawSquare()
    {
        Square mySquare = new Square(length);
        myArea = mySquare.GetArea();
        myBoundary = mySquare.GetBoundLength(length);
        lblAreaResult.Text = myArea.ToString();
        lblBoundaryLength.Text = myBoundary.ToString();
    }

    public void drawTriangle()
    {
        Triangle myTriangle = new Triangle(length);
        myArea = myTriangle.GetArea();
        myBoundary = myTriangle.GetBoundLength();
        lblAreaResult.Text = myArea.ToString();
        lblBoundaryLength.Text = myBoundary.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: So? whats your question?

Comment: How do I go about drawing the shapes onto the panel using values from the track bar.

Comment: Drawing in `WinForms` is event driven. Hook onto the `Paint` event of the panel and draw there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `Panel`'s `Paint` event like this:

```
private void pnlDrawArea_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
        int offset = 20;
        Rectangle bounding = new Rectangle(offset, offset, 
                            (int)myBoundary.Value, (int)myBoundary.Value);

        if (rbSquare.Checked)
        {
           e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, bounding);
        }
        else if (rbCircle.Checked)
        {
           e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, bounding);
        }
        // else if...

}
```

and in your `updateShape` simply call the `Paint` event by coding: `pnlDrawArea.Invalidate();`

For the triangle you will

- use the `DrawLines` methos and
- have to calculate three `Points` for it
- add them to an array or a list..

Don't forget to hook up the `Paint` event!!

Comment: That works great thank you! But one question, is there a way I can limit the size of the graphic to the size of the panel?

Comment: What do you mean? The Panel/Controls's surface will always __limit__ the drawing. You can further limit the drawing with a Graphics by setting a Graphics clipping region. Or do you mean __scaling__ the drawing to fit into the Panel? Yes, you can do that too: First determine the sizes of the Panel (simple) and the drawing. For this you will have to write a loop and caluculate the four min and max values for x and y. Then you can calcculate a scaling factor and set it with a MultiplyTransform(Matrix.Scale)..